# How to say "If you should..." or "Should you..."

Tags: expressions

> Si vous **deviez** mourir et renaître aujourd’hui, choisiriez-vous d’être à nouveau une femme ?

I understand that the verb "devoir" has the meaning of "should" in the sense of duty and obligation. On the other hand, can you also use "devoir" to mean "should", only this time indicating a low probability instead, as in the sentence above?

How does using "deviez" differ in meaning from the following?

> Si vous **mouriez** et **renaissiez** aujourd’hui, choisiriez-vous d’être à nouveau une femme ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a way to emphasize the starting postulate, a way to say that the hypothetical situation is a given, maybe to avoid someone questioning that before even considering the asked choice. However, in its general meaning it is indeed a simple assertion, extremely close in sense to the variant you quoted at the end of your question, which could definitely be used and would probably sound just as good.

But I guess it's the same for some uses of *to have to* or *must*. What whould you think of the 'duty' meaning in the following example ?

> If you **had to** be either a klingon or a borg, what would you choose ?

Comment: I was under the impression that my first sentence with "Si vous **deviez mourir**" means "If you **should** die" or "**Should** you die". The use of "**should**" in an if-clause indicates a much lower possibility of that particular thing actually happening than when saying "If you **died** today" which I assume is equal to "Si vous **mouriez**". I wonder if the same distinction applies in French. Merci.

Comment: I ....agree. Your initial question had made me assume that you already knew or foresaw part of the explanation, but now I wonder what you in fact **don't** understand here. Yes, it's similar in french and english, so..... what's the very point of your question, I must have missed it ?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't sure if the Imparfait form "**devais/devions/deviez**" of the verb "**devoir**" can indeed be used to compose a "**Should you...**" clause. So regarding my interpretation of the distinction between the two sentences, am I on the right track here? Merci.

Comment: Not sure that 'si vous deviez mourir' indicates a much lower possibility than 'si vous mourriez' (double R please). Maybe it's even the contrary, I would use 'devoir' if I suspected that the person will not answer or will answer something like 'I ain't dying so move on'. Like 'But if you HAD to, answer!'. But I think it's very subtle and both sound the same to me. 'Vous devriez' is 'You should', but 'Vous deviez' is 'You had to'.

Comment: I agree with Simon Dechamps, I don't see a difference in the two example, both grammatically correct by the way. The first exemple (si vous deviez) sounds a lot better to my ears though.